# Visual Studio 2008 - Is it possible for two projects to share common classes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, projects

In Visual Studio 2008 I know its possible to have one solution with two (or more) projects.

Is it possible OR How is it possible for the projects to share common class files?

For example -> Project 1 has a log file handling class.  Can Project 2 reference it?

My hope is to increase code re-use and avoid two copies of the same thing that need to be maintained.

The target is Winforms C# (3.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible. You need to add a reference to Project 1 from Project 2 (right-click Project 2 in the Solution Explorer, choose "Add Reference...", and choose Project 1 under the "Projects" tab).

Don't forget that the code for Project 1 and Project 2 is likely to be in different namespaces. You'll need to add the appropriate `using` statement(s).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, one project can reference the other one. Simply choose `Add reference > Projects` and select the project to be referenced.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to move non-application specific common functionality to a library that is on it's own development track and reference that from both.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually want the class to be in two projects.  You want it to be in project A, and then add a reference from project B to project A.  This will allow you to use the class in both projects.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called "Adding a Reference."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5zwxxdw(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project that you want to *use* the common classes nd select "Add Reference...".  In the dalog that appears, choose the "Projects" tab and select the project that *contains* the common classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also compile your classes you wanna use an put the to the global assembly cache

Comment: Throwing everything in the GAC is inviting version nightmares. This is especially fun when you make a change to a library, throw it in the GAC, and a few days later all of your apps start breaking and the other developers don't know why.

Comment: You are completely right david. I just wanted to show this other option